# Getting the current logged-in user in PageModel in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am building a Razor Pages based application in ASP.NET Core 3.1. I started with a project template, which has a login partial showing the currently logged-in user on the page. When I log-in to the application, it shows the username on the page correctly. Code in this partial looks like this (non-important lines omitted):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

Hello @User.Identity.Name!
```

In the PageModel class of another page I want to access the information of currently logged in user, but the value of User property is null,  when I'm logged in.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: May be this link can give you some idea https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-razor-pages-simple-login-using-entity-framework-database-first-app/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this code to get the login user's info :

```
 var user = this.User.Identity;
```

You can also refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: The OP is saying the User property in the Model is null so this.User is never going to work